# Reporting Poorly Secured Non-Public Use Federally Funded Data

Tags: government, releasing-data, nonprofit, security

I work for a non-profit and recently I applied for access to non-publicly available data. My concern is that this data is not very well protected, as it potentially contains personally identifiable information, and all it took to access it was a URL.

This data comes from another non-profit that is predominantly federally funded. I know this stack exchange is focused primarily on open data, but does anyone know where / how I might go about reporting my concern? Is there a federal agency for this sort of thing?

Comment: This is a worthy question in general, although it's not really appropriate for this site. You should definitely take your concern to the organization which publishes the data. You may also want to copy their funders to your correspondence, although also if this other org is a competitor, they may read that as aggro. / Normally you'd take something like this to the FTC, but I don't think they have jurisdiction over non-profits. / You may want to learn more about Carl Malamud's work with public.resource.org. He's a tireless activist for open data and good privacy practices.

Comment: Although the context specifically about data that has access control, I would think that the issue of what to do about reporting data that should *not* be open because of an issue like SBU (sensitive but unclassified information) could be appropriate for this site.